# return product column from database with exploded column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi everyone in my Products table i have product_properties that should return as an array with other columns I could do

```
$Product = Product::find(33);
$properties = explode(",", ($Product ->product_properties));
```

but I will get product_properties as an array but will not return other product columns https://prnt.sc/mbp3tk  all that i need is to return product_properties as an array with other columns like in image https://prnt.sc/mbp2yh but in image, product_properties is not an array

Comment: I think you should try this:
$Product = Product::find(33);
$Product->properties = explode(",", ($Product ->product_properties));

Comment: @Naco  i need to return other  product columns as well

Comment: yes, you just 'override' the product_properties inside $product object, and then return $product or dump($product), all other coulmns will be present. 
and a hint, you can specify columns you want as second param of find; $Product = Product::find(33, ['product_name', 'product_description'])

Comment: @Naco How to override product_properties  ??

Comment: like this $Product ->product_properties = explode(",", $Product ->product_properties);

Comment: @Naco Thanks man you saved my life

Comment: Is the value you have for `product_properties` an array before you save it or just a csv?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like a JSON object to me. Did you try to encode/decode it as a JSON object?
[Check the documentation if you like](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `product_properties` is an array before you save it to the database you could just use the [$casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) property on the model:

```
$casts = ['product_properties' => 'array'];
```

This will mean that you can set `product_properties` on the model as an array and it will convert it to JSON to store to the database, then when you go to access the property on the model it will be an array e.g.

```
$product->product_properties = ['foo', 'bar'];
$product->save();
```

---

Alternatively, if you just want to change the property on the model but not have Eloquent convert it to store it to the database you could use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) instead:

```
public function  getProductPropertiesAttribute($properties)
{
    return explode(',', $properties);
}
```